I have trouble getting piezoelectric test by OWON VDS1022 oscilloscope
I want to do piezoelectric tests on some disc shape samples that are made using FDM. I have an OWON VDS1022 oscilloscope.
When I put a napkin between the electrodes and make force, the oscilloscope shows peaks on the screen. When I make an impact on the electrode surface with something like a pencil I also get peaks. I have no idea what should I do.


What is a "piezoelectic test?" 2. What is "FDM?" 3. What do you expect from the test? 4. What is different between your expectation and what the oscilloscope shows?


What test you are trying to do? What do you expect to happen? Getting voltage pulses when tapping piezo discs is the expected outcome.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
